# Run Time Error 91 VBA - Attempting to Set a Worksheet but it keeps saying run time error?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set PendingSheet = PendingDoc.Worksheets("Pending")
```

this is the intial code that wont let me set the item?

Comment: `PendingDoc` has no value assigned or it is not a workbook object. If it is a workbook type with an assigned and valid value, you can query its name in the immediate windows like this: `?PendingDoc.Name`

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pending")`, if it is in Excel. Make sure that `Dim PendingSheet as Worksheet` exists before assigning.

Comment: the pending worksheet is in a workbook that i have set previously, and it looks like this:

Comment: ```Set PendingDoc = Application.Workbooks.Open(thisfolder & "Pending.xlsx")
Set InfoDoc = Application.Workbooks.Open(thisfolder & "StudentInfo.xlsx")
Set PartcDoc = Application.Workbooks.Open(thisfolder & "PartC.xlsx")

Set Pendingws = PendingDoc.Worksheets("pending")
Set Infows = InfoDoc.Worksheets("StudentInfo")
Set Partcws = PartcDoc.Worksheets("PartC")
```

Comment: ahh i just didnt reference the object correctly thanks